# convert string (with structure object) to object

Tags: javascript

I have a json information and I want to use it to create an **object** like this one:

```
var legends = {

    "Altimetry" : {
        0 : {
            legenrowname : "0m - 250m    ",
            fillcolor : "005500",
            bordercolor : ""
        },
        1 : {
            legenrowname : "250m - 1000m ",
            fillcolor : "ffff7f",
            bordercolor : ""
        },
        2 : {
            legenrowname : "1000m - 5000m ",
            fillcolor : "B47811",
            bordercolor : ""
        },
        3 : {
            legenrowname : "+ 5000m       ",
            fillcolor : "482400",
            bordercolor : ""
        }
    }
};

alert(legends); //the result is this:
Object []
```

it´s recognize as an object (that´s what I need in the next step)

Now, I´m trying to create it dynamically with legends2

```
var dataL = ${dataJsonLegends};
var legends2 ="";
var lengthL = dataL.length;
$.each(dataL, function(i, item){
legendName = item.legendname;
legends2= '"' + legendName + '":{';
dataR = item.rows;
var lengthR = dataR.length;
$.each(dataR, function(j, item2){
    id=item2.uid;
    rowname=item2.legendrowname;
    fillcolor=item2.fillcolor;
    rowobject = id + ' : { legenrowname:"' + rowname + '", fillcolor:"' + fillcolor + '"}';
    if(j!=lengthR-1) rowobject = rowobject + ",";

    legends2= legends2+ rowobject;
});
legends2= legends2+ '}';
if(i!=lengthL-1) legends2= legends2+ ",";
});
alert(legends2); //the result is this:

"Altimetry" : { 0 : {       legenrowname : "0m - 250m    ",
            fillcolor : "005500",
            bordercolor : ""
    },1 : {
            legenrowname : "250m - 1000m ",
            fillcolor : "ffff7f",
            bordercolor : ""
    },2 : {
            legenrowname : "1000m - 5000m ",
            fillcolor : "B47811",
            bordercolor : ""
    },3 : {
            legenrowname : "+ 5000m       ",
            fillcolor : "482400",
            bordercolor : ""
    }}
```

The legends2 value is what I expected but I want it to be recognize as an object and not as an string with object structure.

I tried many things to solve it. `JSON.parse`, `eval`, etc... but no one works.

¿Could someone help or give me a tip?

Edited: incoming json

I post my json object (dataL), which I use to create the structure I need.

```
[{"uid":1,"legendname":"Altimetry","legend_description":null,"rows":[{"uid":2,"legendrowname":"250m - 1000m","fillcolor":"ffff7f","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null},{"uid":4,"legendrowname":"+ 5000m","fillcolor":"482400","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null},{"uid":1,"legendrowname":"0m - 250m","fillcolor":"005500","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null},{"uid":3,"legendrowname":"1000m - 5000m","fillcolor":"B47811","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null}],"layer":{"id":1,"description":"Altimetry","geoserver":"/geoserver/Sopcawind/wms","name":"Sopcawind:srtm","transparent":true,"format":"image/png","viewparams":"","isbaselayer":false,"opacity":0.5,"color":"#2b383b","visibility":false,"groupid":1,"infocontrol":true,"geometry":"","featuretype":"","srs":"","extradata":"","legends":null,"project":null}}];
```

Edited2:
I tried to use the code but I don`t really need a json object. I use a json object to create another basic object with this structure:

```
//loop legends
    legends={"legendname": {
    //loop rows
        row.id : {
            legenrowname : row.legendrowname,
            fillcolor : row.fillcolor,
            bordercolor : row.bordercolor
        }   
    }}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `JSON.parse`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: What's wrong with the JSON.parse that you used?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    (anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do it that complicated, and the Json in the top of your post is invalid.
Maybe this is something that you want?

```
{
    "Altimetry": [
        {
            "legenrowname": "0m - 250m    ",
            "fillcolor": "005500",
            "bordercolor": ""
        },
        {
            "legenrowname": "250m - 1000m ",
            "fillcolor": "ffff7f",
            "bordercolor": ""
        },
        {
            "legenrowname": "1000m - 5000m ",
            "fillcolor": "B47811",
            "bordercolor": ""
        },
        {
            "legenrowname": "+ 5000m       ",
            "fillcolor": "482400",
            "bordercolor": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Check your incoming JSON with http://jsonlint.com/ if it's valid.
Did you generate the JSON yourself?
do a console.log(jsonString) and paste it to jsonlint.

With a valid piece of JSON, you can use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`- do not add any extra brackets 
like `var dataL = ${dataJsonLegends};`

Right now it looks like you're looping over every single character in your response string

EDIT

Your updated JSON is valid, this is how I would process it:

```
var json = [{"uid":1,"legendname":"Altimetry","legend_description":null,"rows":[{"uid":2,"legendrowname":"250m - 1000m","fillcolor":"ffff7f","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null},{"uid":4,"legendrowname":"+ 5000m","fillcolor":"482400","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null},{"uid":1,"legendrowname":"0m - 250m","fillcolor":"005500","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null},{"uid":3,"legendrowname":"1000m - 5000m","fillcolor":"B47811","bordercolor":null,"rast_value":null,"fillcolorrgb":null,"bordercolorrgb":null,"legendrow_description":null,"legend":null}],"layer":{"id":1,"description":"Altimetry","geoserver":"/geoserver/Sopcawind/wms","name":"Sopcawind:srtm","transparent":true,"format":"image/png","viewparams":"","isbaselayer":false,"opacity":0.5,"color":"#2b383b","visibility":false,"groupid":1,"infocontrol":true,"geometry":"","featuretype":"","srs":"","extradata":"","legends":null,"project":null}}];


for(i = 0; i<json.length; i++) {
    console.log("new array item");
    console.log(json[i].uid);
    console.log(json[i].legendname);
    console.log(json[i].legenddescription);
    for(j = 0; j<json[i].rows.length; j++) {
        console.log("new row");
        console.log('\t' + json[i].rows[j].uid);
        console.log('\t' + json[i].rows[j].legendrowname);
        console.log('\t' + json[i].rows[j].fillcolor);
        console.log('\t' + json[i].rows[j].bordercolor);
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

EDIT 2

Why not just create as javascript objects then, if you need the json after just stringify

something like this (maybe not exact):

```
var objArr = new [];
$.each(dataL, function(i, item){
    var leg = new Object();
    leg.uid = item.uid;
    leg.legendname = item.legendname;
    leg.rows = [];
    $.each(dataR, function(j, item2){
        var rw = new Object();
        rw.uid = item2.uid;
        rw.legendrowname = item2.legendrowname
        // and so on
        leg.rows.push(rw);
    });
    objArr.push(leg);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(objArr));
```

Comment: I create the json from an object in the logic part of the app with Json library (it should be valid). But the structure needed in the js follows different need. As I show in the example, it must be something like the static part of the example. The static part works fine. I will verify the incoming JSON.

Comment: I verified the json and is valid

Comment: Can you add the incoming JSON to the post?

Comment: Maybe I´m not being clear enough. Ok, so you iterate the json with for-s. I don´t have any problem showing and printing the information. My main problem is when I need to create an object with a defined structure with the information that I have in the json object (see static part in the example: legends). When I try to build the structure the result is being recognized as an string, and I need to convert it to an object.

Comment: Hey, this last one could be useful for me. With some changes to find the structure, I think it could work. Thank you, I´ll keep you posted.

Comment: I tried to use the code you gave me, but I don`t really need a json object. I need a object with another structure using the json var information. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The output is lacking braces around it. Add those and it should work.